# Proper syntax for .htaccess Rewrite

Tags: 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm very new at this so apologies if this is too easy, but would this be proper syntax for redirecting an entire site to a new domain? This is what was suggested so my other concern is blank lines, spaces, etc. Thanks

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Entire Site to New Domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes that's correct and would 301 redirect everything on `oldsite.org` to the same path on `http://newsite.com`. Plenty of similar questions on the StackExchange network such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001173/htaccess-301-redirect-from-old-domain-to-new-domain-while-structure-of-pages-an).

Comment: Thanks Geoff. @krokola directed me to that question but I just wanted to be absolutely certain.